# How do I calculate similar matrix with arbitrary change of base matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$P=[\begin{matrix}\overrightarrow v_1 & \overrightarrow v_2 & \overrightarrow v_3\end{matrix}]$ with $\overrightarrow v_1$, $\overrightarrow v_2$, $\overrightarrow v_3 \in \Bbb R^3$ and
$A= \left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)$

How do I find $P^{-1}AP$?

I don't want to just take the matrix product because that will take a long time.

Comment: Well, just calculate the matrix product.

Comment: There is no easy solution. If it takes too long, just pay someone to do it for you, or use a computer with a program that does matrix multiplication and inversion.